# ')' Error in a sout+tab statement

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm making a code for a game but in 1 particular class i seem to be getting an error from a simple system.out.println I am new to programming i just started recently and i know this is a basic error but i really dont

```
public static int victory1(){
        String[] weaponName = {"Fist","Iron Sword","Metal Dick Axe",
    };
        int[] weaponDamage = {2,4,6
    };
        String[] armorName = { "Iron Leather Coat",       
    };
        int[] armorDef = { 4,
    };
    System.out.println("After defeating the Iron Leathered Boar you decide wether to make an armor or a sword out of its skin.\n"
                    + "1)Craft Armor (Obtain"+armorName[0]+")"" +"+armorDef[0]+" Armor\n"
                    + "2)Craft Sword (Obtain"+weaponName[1]+")"" +"+armorDef[1]+" Damage");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"1)Craft Armor (Obtain"+armorName[0]+")"" +"+armorDef[0]+" Armor\n"
"2)Craft Sword (Obtain"+weaponName[1]+")"" +"+armorDef[1]+" Damage");
```

to

```
"1)Craft Armor (Obtain"+armorName[0]+")"+armorDef[0]+" Armor\n"
"2)Craft Sword (Obtain"+weaponName[1]+")"+armorDef[1]+" Damage");
```